How can I tell if my github branch has a Pull Request?
I tried passing the most recent SHA to Commit.get_pulls but that does not give expected results.    It returns an empty paginatedList even though I have a PR for the SHA in question . . .
I'm using the Git Library for Python to get the latest SHA in my local repo, with:
latest_sha = local_repo.commit().hexsha
Then I'm trying to get the PR associated with that SHA from github:
commit = github.get_commit(latest_sha)
pulls = commit.get_pulls()          

But pulls is always empty.
Any advice?  Thanks!!

Please show the relevant code, and possibly the relevant repository.
